# Using 8-1 Multiplexer with atmega16

Tags: c, isr

I am trying to use a `8-1 multiplexer` with at `mega16` trying to maximize my input pins 
so i made my program to scan all the addresses of the `multiplexer` and listen to an `interrupt` if an interrupt happens the program check which address was sent at this moment then print a string on LCD (and it is managed by switch case) ...

**THE PROBLEM IS** ::
*when an interrupt happens it get in to the switch case and execute all the cases under the one it starts on*

**EX**:
if i pressed the first button(First address) it will execute all the cases,
but if i pressed the second one it will execute it' case and the third case ans so on

```
int main(void)
{
    //////////////////////
    SETMUSK(MCUCR,ISC01);
    /* When(ISC01 =1 and ISC00 =0 )The falling edge of INT0 generates an interrupt request. so we can use Internal PUll UP Resistance*/
    CLEARMUSK(MCUCR,ISC00);
    ///////////////////////


    GICR = 0x40;
        CLEARMUSK(SFIOR,PUD); //Enabling Pull up resistor
        DDRC = 0xFF;



    LCD_Init();


    DDRC = 0xFF;
    DDRA = 0xFF;
    DDRD = 0x00;



        LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);
            LCD_display_string("Program Starting !!");
            _delay_ms(250);
            _delay_ms(250);
            _delay_ms(250);
            _delay_ms(250);
            _delay_ms(250);
            _delay_ms(250);
            _delay_ms(250);
            LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);


    sei(); // enabling global interrupt musk
    while(1)
    {


          for (PORTA=0x00;PORTA <= 7;PORTA++) ;

        //TODO:: Please write your application code 
    }

}

ISR(INT0_vect)/*sending the ISR address to the vector table using this statement here (INT0_vect)*/
{ 

    switch (PINA)
        {
            case Addr0 :
            {
                LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);
            LCD_display_string("First");
            _delay_ms(200);

            LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);


            break;
            }


            case Addr1 :
            {
            LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);
            LCD_display_string("Second");
            _delay_ms(200);

            LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);

            break;
            }

            case Addr2 :
            {
                LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);
            LCD_display_string("Third");
            _delay_ms(200);

            LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);

            break;
            }



            case Addr3 :
            {
                LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);
            LCD_display_string("Fourth");
            _delay_ms(250);

            LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);

            break;
            }



            case Addr4 :
            {
                LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);
            LCD_display_string("FiFth");
            _delay_ms(250);

            LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);

            break;

            }

            case Addr5 :
            {
                LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);
            LCD_display_string("sixth");
            _delay_ms(250);

            LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);

            break;

            }

            case Addr6 :
            {
                LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);
            LCD_display_string("seventh");
            _delay_ms(250);

            LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);
            break;
            }


            case Addr7 :
            {
                LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);
            LCD_display_string("eights");
            _delay_ms(250);

            LCD_send_command(CLEAR_DISPLAY_AND_RAM);
            break;
            }


            //default:
            //break;
        }

}
```

MUX.h 

    `{
       #define Addr0  0x00 //00000000
        #define Addr1  0x01 //00000001 
        #define Addr2  0x02 //00000010
        #define Addr3  0x03 //00000011
        #define Addr4  0x04 //00000100
        #define Addr5  0x05 //00000101
        #define Addr6  0x06 //00000110
        #define Addr7  0x07 //00000111
     }`

Comment: Please give more information Addr0,Also you should clear the interrupt flag bit(if any) while you enter the ISR.

Comment: Sorry 
Addr0 is written in a .h file